# Sql Server Performance And Order Of Fields

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

**does the order of fields creation in a table  effect on the performance of commands on the table?**
*If the answer is yes, can anyone discuss it?*

For example i have create a table like this

```
create table Software(int id,alpha datetime,beta datetime,title nvarchar(100),stable datetime,description nvarchar(200) )
```

if i change it to

```
create table Software(int id,alpha datetime,beta datetime,stable datetime,description nvarchar(200),title nvarchar(100) )
```

Is there any performance effect ?

Is it clear?

Comment: I can't fully answer this question.  But I will add that in my years working with SqlServer there have been many times when all of a sudden queries have become "inefficient" (i.e. index not being used) because of very obsure reasons (addition of new fields).

Comment: @M Schenkel: those reasons are not obscure: 9 times out of 10 the statistics or indexes would have needed rebuilding

Comment: +1 for Mitch - we've had this problem before but it was because we didn't update our covering indexes to include the new column.

Comment: @taspeotis - Yep. That and fragmentation seem viable explanations. No idea what the effect on existing statistics is supposed to be though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field *order* makes *no difference whatsoever* (if the fields are always the same of course)

The on-disk structure will remain the same pretty much regardless. Simply:

- header
- fixed length columns
- null bitmap
- variable length columns

All you're doing above is rearranging some columns inside the "fixed length" and "variable length" sections. However, the same processing is required to retrieve them no matter which order they are in.

See [Paul Randal's article](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Inside-the-Storage-Engine-Anatomy-of-a-record.aspx)

Comment: But i didn't get my answer yet.Maybe we must deep in data storing technique of sql server.

Comment: @Lightwing: I said "no difference whatsoever". What more do you need...?

Comment: @LightWing: If gbn's answer does not satisfy you, I'm not sure what kind of answer you are after. The order does not make difference, because it's implemented this way. The record structure is explained in the article gbn linked. What's still not clear?

Comment: Thanks for the article **I got my answer Thanks.The question finished here.**

Comment: @LightWing: in order of creation as far as I know. So an ALTER TABLE to add a column will append at the end. I think you maybe need another question if you now mean "does order of WHERE clause matter" (based on a comment above). This questions is too busy to be modified now.

Comment: There is an absolutely miniscule difference in that a `NULL` or empty column at the end of the variable length section consumes no space at all so if either `title` or `description` were more likely to be `NULL` one ordering might be marginally more compact.

Answer (score 3):

No. This will not affect performance.

Comment: why? can you discuss why the answer is no?

Comment: It's up to the database to deal with this sort of thing.  In most cases, you'd be much better off to focus on tuning your queries and indexes.  There is certainly some performance effect of anything you do, but it will be so small for something like this, that it probably won't be measurable, and may well change in a future service pack or anything.  Microsoft doesn't really publish enough information to really know how the table field order could affect queries.

Comment: @squawknull: "Microsoft doesn't really publish enough information to really know how the table field order could affect queries." - actually it does.  The only thing that different ordering of columns can affect is row storage (but its only a small difference): place the variable length columns last...(and try to make all columns non-nullable if Domain permits)

Comment: In a table that have over 40 fileds and there are different types of large and small data. The order of fields is not important? Or order of conditions in a where clause

Comment: In a perfect world, it shouldn't matter, and the query optimizer would always choose the best query plan regardless of ordering of columns, etc.  That said, my experience with SQL Server in the past has been that little things can make a difference, but even the best SQL Server DBA's I've worked with often end up relegated to trial and error when dealing with those tricky issues.  More recent versions of SQL Server haven't been so bad, but through many hours of optimizing SQL Server queries, I've come to realization that the SQL Server query optimizer can be very unpredictable sometimes.

Comment: @LightWing - you can read a little about how things are stored here: http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Inside-the-Storage-Engine-Anatomy-of-a-record.aspx I think it may confuse more than enlighten but the bottom line is that any effect caused by column order will be negligible to nil.

Answer (score -3):

The field order can have a very subtle effect on performance and how often maintenance operations will have to take place. In the grand scheme of things, it would be a significantly better use of your time to:

- Build/Test indexes
- Restructure queries
- Partition tables (horizontally & vertically)
- Alter the filegroup architecture

That is not an exhaustive list.

You didn't mention if you've already tuned any of those things and are still needing to squeeze some extra ms out of the process.

Comment: @gbn Just because you don't like something doesn't mean you have to get all testy about it.

Comment: You have posted misleading information on an authoritative public web site. And didn't answer the question. Whether I like or dislike is irrelevant: but this answer shouldn't be here...

Comment: @gbn I disagree that my answer is misleading. The comments of @squawknull and @Mitch Wheat (on Henry's reply) adopt the same point of view. Did I catch your ire because I did not ***authoritatively*** state my reply while referencing an article that is irrelevant to my answer? If anything, it's misleading to state that column order ***has no effect whatsoever***. BTW, you might want to review the FAQ where it mentions "Be Nice." I don't think being snarky toward the OP fits that mold. I'm in this to learn, not to be attacked by those who disagree with me.